# Pandas: adding multiindex Series/Dataframes containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, addition, dataframe, series

How do I add / merge two multiindex Series/DataFrames which contain lists as elements (a port-sequence or timestamp-sequence in my case). Especially, how to deal with indices, which appear only in one Series/DataFrame? Unfortunately, the `.add()`-method allows only floats for the `fill_value` argument, not empty lists.

My Data:

```
print series1
print series2

IP               sessionID
195.12*.21*.11*  49                    [5900]
                 50         [5900, 5900, 5900, 5900, ...

IP               sessionID
85.15*.24*.12*   63                    [3389]
91.20*.4*.14*    68           [445, 445, 139]
113.9*.4*.16*    75                 [23, 210]
195.12*.21*.11*  49                    [5905]
```

Expected result:

```
IP               sessionID
195.12*.21*.11*  49              [5900, 5905]
                 50         [5900, 5900, 5900, 5900, ...
85.15*.24*.12*   63                    [3389]
91.20*.4*.14*    68           [445, 445, 139]
113.9*.4*.16*    75                 [23, 210]
```

Oddly enough, `series1.add(series1)` or `series2.add(series2)` does work and appends the lists as expected, however `series1.add(series2)` produces runtime errors. `series1.combine_first(series2)` works, however it does not merge the lists - it simply takes one. Any ideas?

*Yes, I know that lists as elements are bad style, but that's the way my data is right now. Sorry for that. To keep it short I just have posted the series example, let me know if you also need the DataFrame example.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there is any other poor ghost out there which needs this info...
It seems like a dirty work-around, but it works:

```
# add() works for mutual indices, so find intersection and call it
# fortunately, it appends list2 to list1!
intersection = series1.index.intersection(series2.index)
inter1 = series1[series1.index.isin(intersection)]
inter2 = series2[series2.index.isin(intersection)]
interAppend = inter1.add(inter2)

# combine_first() unions indices and keeps the values of the caller,
# so it will keep the appended lists on mutual indices,
# while it adds new indices and corresponding values
exclusiveAdd = interAppend.combine_first(series1).combine_first(series2)
```