# Groupby multiindex pandas series using agg to sum AND apply list

Tags: python, pandas

I have two multiindex series

series 1

```
Company Name     Product     Price        TransactionID
Company A        Apple       10           T0001
Company B        Grapes      20           T0002
                 Orange      30           T0003
```

series 2

```
Company Name     Product     Price        TransactionID
Company A        Orange      10           T0004
                 Apple       20           T0005
Company B        Orange      20           T0006
```

I want to form the series like below

```
Company Name     Product     Sum_price    TransactionID
Company A        Orange      10           [T0004]
                 Apple       30           [T0001,T0005]
Company B        Orange      50           [T0003,T0006]
                 Grapes      20           [T0002]
```

From [Group dataframe and get sum AND count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174155/group-dataframe-and-get-sum-and-count) shows that I can use .agg to do sum and count at the same time, but how to apply .apply(list)  and sum together? Right now, I have applied the code [Pandas: adding multiindex Series/Dataframes containing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015479/pandas-adding-multiindex-series-dataframes-containing-lists) to form two series one is sum and another one is the one with transactionID. I think I can concat two series together, but I just want to see whether there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate by [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) with `sum` and converting to `list`:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .groupby(['Company Name', 'Product'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'Price':'sum', 'TransactionID': lambda x: x.tolist()})
     )
print (df)
  Company Name Product  Price   TransactionID
0    Company A   Apple     30  [T0001, T0005]
1    Company A  Orange     10         [T0004]
2    Company B  Grapes     20         [T0002]
3    Company B  Orange     50  [T0003, T0006]
```

Comment: if it is a pandas series instead of a dataframe, will it be different?

Comment: @PlataleaMinor - Try change `pd.concat([df1, df2])` to `pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()])`

Answer (score 1):

You can first concat both of your dataframes like this:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

After this, you can use groupby agg to do the sum and also use a lambda function to concatenate the lists

```
df3 = df3.groupby(['Company', 'Name', 'Product']).agg({'Price':sum, 'TransactionID': lambda x: [i for i in x]})
```

You will then end up with the desired output like so:

```
Company Name     Product     Sum_price    TransactionID
Company A        Orange      10           [T0004]
                 Apple       30           [T0001,T0005]
Company B        Orange      50           [T0003,T0006]
                 Grapes      20           [T0002]
```